# Axios mixin call order in Vue

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to create a Vue mixin which would handle my Axios calls (I need to do a lot of similar calls from different components).

Mixin code is like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

const restService = {
    methods: {
        executeRequest( url, payload ) {
            axios
                .post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    return response.data;
                })
        }
    }
}

export default restService
```

Which I then call from my component like this:

```
import restService from "@/services/RestService";

export default {
    //...
    mixins: [restService],
    methods: {
        saveChanges() {
            //...
            let response = this.executeAuthorizedRequest( changeData );

            this.$notify({
                //some logic that depends on my response object
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `.then()` from the mixin is for some reason called later than my `this.notify()` from component which leads to an error.

Is there a way to make sure that `.then()` is called before proceeding? The same axios code works as expected when written in component method itself.

I'm relatively new to JS frameworks so maybe I don't understand something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios calls are asynchronous. So the response may not be returned before `this.notify()`. You may consider rewriting the axios calls with `async/await` or `Promise` to make sure the response is returned. Here is an example with `async/await`:

```js
import axios from "axios";

const restService = {
  methods: {
    executeRequest(url, payload) {
      return axios
        .post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
    }
  }
}

export default restService
```

And use the call like:

```js
import restService from "@/services/RestService";

export default {
    //...
    mixins: [restService],
    methods: {
        async saveChanges() {
            //...
            let response = await this.executeAuthorizedRequest( changeData );
            
            this.$notify({
                // do anything here with response.data
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I came up with a different solution in the meantime: I too return `axios.post()` in my `executeRequest()` method, and in the `saveChanges()` method i call `.then( response => {} )` on it which contains all the required logic, has full access to response and also solves the async problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try out to use `async/await` when you call the method and inside the method just return the request :

```
import axios from "axios";

const restService = {
    methods: {
        executeRequest( url, payload ) {
           return axios.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                })
                
        }
    }
}

export default restService
```

then call it like :

```
import restService from "@/services/RestService";

export default {
    //...
    mixins: [restService],
    methods: {
       async saveChanges() {
            //...
            let response = await this.executeAuthorizedRequest( changeData );

            this.$notify({
                //some logic that depends on my response object
            });
        }
    }
}
```